# Polygon created by subtracted polygons

Tags: algorithm, polygon, clipping

[image: Sample polygon and its illustrated holes]

Above is a polygon (gray area) where I subtracted 4 polygons (red, green, purple, and blue areas). Is there a way to get the vertices of the created *sub*-polygon (small gray polygon)?

[image: Sample polygon, holes removed]

The polygons can be of any shape. Also, the side subtracted polygon can lie on the side of the main polygon (that's why I did not call it hole).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look into clipping algorithms like [Vatti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatti_clipping_algorithm). Or may be you want some port or binding of [gpc](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software/).

Comment: Thanks. I am now using the gpc.

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm:**

My proposal is in this particular case that you make an UNION operation of those bright colored polygons. After operation the solution consists of two polygons: The outer which has an orientation CW and a hole polygon which has an orientation of CCW. You need this hole polygon and to know which one of those two is a hole, you can calculate the area of both. The polygon with negative area is a hole polygon.

---

**Implementation:**

Clipper library provides you the needed UNION operation and the area calculation operation (as well as many other operations also).

Clipper is available in eg. C++, C#, Delphi and Javascript.

C++, C#, Delphi:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/polyclipping/

Javascript: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/
Demo: http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/6.2.1.0/main_demo.html

The image below is a screenshot of Clipper Javascript Demo. The operation is INTERSECT.

[image]